# Admob serve campaign ads based on variables

Tags: admob, ads

I have an application on iOS and Android, both serving banner ads through Admob.

I want to be able to show direct sold campaign ads to specific users based on the information they give to the app. For example only serving an ad to people who might actually be interested in it based on the interests they selected in the app.

The app has a list of topics that the user might want ads from. Currently Firebase Cloud Messaging is being used for sending notifications to groups. Is it possible to use these groups as targets for the campaign?

Thanks

Comment: that's not possible. See this link for available targeting options https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6231370?hl=en

Comment: Custom event is available for Mediation but that will not help in this scenario https://developers.google.com/admob/android/custom-events